# Create link inside html table

Tags: php, codeigniter, html-table

I have the following code to generate a table

```
    $query = $this->search_employee->getAll($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));

    $this->table->set_heading('Name', 'Department');
    $tmp = array ( 'table_open'  => '<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" width="70%">' );
    $this->table->set_template($tmp);

    $data['main_content'] = 'display_professors';
    $data['table'] = $this->table->generate($query);
```

My question is how could I create a link under to each row under the Name column that links to view_employee/ID

I am using codeigniter's [table class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/table.html).

Answer (score 2):

There might be a better way to do this, but I simply loop through query rows to create table rows:

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $this->table->add_row(anchor('view_employee/ID/' . $row->employee_id, $row->employee_name), $row->employee_department);
    }
}

$data['table'] = $this->table->generate();
```

etc...

**UPDATE:**

Per your comment to this answer, I don't see how this method is anymore putting html into the model than your own example. After all, either way all you'll do in the view is `<?= $table; ?>`, or similar.

If you absolutely want to separate the two, you could do:

```
$data['rows'] = array();    

if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $this_row = array();
        $this_row['link'] = site_url('view_employee/ID/' . $row->employee_id);
        $this_row['employee_name'] = $row->employee_name;
        $this_row['employee_department'] = $row->employee_department;

        $data['rows'][] = $this_row;
    }
}
```

and then in the view:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" width="70%">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Department</th>
  </tr>
<? foreach($rows as $row): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="<?= $row['link']; ?>"><?= $row['employee_name']; ?></a></td>
    <td><?= $row['employee_department']; ?></td>
  </tr>
<? endforeach; ?>
</table>
```